# Django dynamic URL in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

How can I use template variable in dynamic url. I want something like this:

```
href="{% url '{{ questionnaire.url }}' %}"
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
Reverse for '{{ questionnaire.url }}' not found. '{{ questionnaire.url }}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Update:

The problem is here in my javascript:

```
<script>
let el = `<a href="{% url '${questionnaire.url}' %}"></a>
</script>
```

I insert this code in my template dynamic, and the Django template cant resolve the url correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) documentation. You can pass a view name and Django will resolve it:

*view.py*

```
path('some-url/', app_views.client, name='app-views-client')
```

*index.html*

```
<a href="{% url 'app-views-client' %}" >Go</a>
```

Comment: i know but I get the view name from this {{ questionnaire.url }}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag

```
{% with my_url=questionnaire.url %}
   <a href="{% url my_url %}">Go</a>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Then the error is here: ```href="{% url {{ my_url }} %}" ```. Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'.

Comment: remove {{ }} just keep `my_url`

Comment: I keep getting an error. Reverse for 'my_url' not found. 'my_url' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: just print what y get in `my_url`

Comment: It does not print out anything.

Comment: does `questionnaire.url` have a value

Comment: I have updated my question below, maybe the problem is in my javascript code, where I defined this <a> tag.